# I am doing 3 consecutive foreach loop and it cost a lot of time? Any better way to solve this puzze?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get gather data from Active Directory using sAmAccountName and create an output like this.

The requirements is to get all the group membership of the samAccountName on the list

**Output**

```
EmployeeID  SamAccountName GroupName 
----------  -------------- ---------
1           name1          g1
1           name1          g2
2           name2          g3
2           name2          g4
2           name2          g1
```

**Input text file:**

List of SamaccountName

```
name1
name2
```

My code below is working but it takes too much time since I am doing 3 consecutive for loop. Is there any better way to make it fast for getting the data? I only need 3 columns which is the ID, samAccountName and the groupName

**My script**

```
$filter = "Depends on the group filter"

$resultHolder = @()
$accountList = Get-Content "C:\Desktop"
foreach($account in $accountList){
    $user = Get-ADUser $account -Properties EmployeeNumber | select EmployeeNumber, name
    foreach ($identity in $user.name) {
        $getAccounts = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $identity | select name | Where-Object { $_.name -like $filter}
        foreach ($group in $getAccounts.name) {
            $table = new-object psobject 
            $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ID" -NotePropertyValue $user.EmployeeNumber
            $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Name" -NotePropertyValue $user.name
            $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Group Name" -NotePropertyValue $group 
            $resultHolder += $table
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is the `MemberOf` property for each `Get-ADUser`. Something like: `Get-Content $TextFile.txt | Get-ADUser -Prop EmployeeNumber,MemberOf | ForEach-Object{ $User=$_; ForEach( $Group in $_.MemberOf ){[PSCustomObject]@{EmployeeID=$User.EmployeeNumber;Name=$User.Name;'Group Name'=$Group.Split(',')[0].Substring(3)}}}`

Comment: This is a great help @TheMadTechnician. I only need to add a specific filter for groups to filter. That is the reason why I use the AD-principalGroupmembership to filter the groups the starts with a specific letters or characters

Comment: What is an example of `$filter` ? This could be very fast if you use LDAPFilter.

Comment: $filter is a parameter that I enter for filtering the groups. Lets say I want all only groups that starting with GTA-access. So that is the usage of the filter. I will only gets all the groups that starts with that and the users from the list

Comment: That would be easy enough, just add that into the group thing like `'Group Name'=$Group.Split(',')[0].Substring(3)|?{$_ -like $filter}`

Comment: Thanks @TheMadTechnician. What I did is stored your code to a variable and calling that and filtering the groups that I only need for the filter! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an AD available at the moment to test but - assumed you have samaccountnames in your account list - something like this should be enough actually:

```
$accountList = Get-Content "C:\Desktop"
$Result =
foreach ($account in $accountList) {
    $user = Get-ADUser $account -Properties EmployeeNumber, MemberOf 
    foreach ($Group in $User.MemberOf) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $user.name
            ID    = $user.EmployeeNumber
            Group = (Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group).Name
        }
    }
$Result
```

To make that even faster you should query all your existing groups in AD once and save it in a lookup table you can use then instead of AD queries t oget the name of the groups.

Comment: Thank you so much @olaf Our AD groups is too large and always changing. getting all groupnames takes a lots of time to run. With these script I am able to do it and maybe put the filter on the get-ad group to get the groups that I need. I will keep you posted when I tried this code

Comment: OK, maybe you don't need **all** groups. But it will be faster anyway when you collect all *needed* group at once in advance before running your script and using the query result as a lookup table.

Comment: I think I see now what you mean!